# Wordpress extra white space on the right

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site and using the TwentyFourteen theme.

I just noticed an extra white margin on the right of the page that goes about 200px in width.
I used Chrome's inspection tool, and I see the width is 1440px when it should be 1240, but I can not see which css file is making it that way.

The site is http://matsoncustomconcrete.com/
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No one can help? I am still struggling with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply hiding the horizontal scrolling bar works and prevents you from scrolling right. Just use: `body style="overflow-x: hidden;"`

Answer (score 0):

```
#site-header img, .site,.site-header {
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

This works

Answer (score 0):

The site width is blocked to 1260px, see the class .site right after body tag.

You can set margin: 0 auto to center align the content or change the value of header and footer to take all the width.